# Highchart multiple column range in same series on bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I needed to make a highchart with multiple columnranges in same series. Please refer the sample screenshot which I am trying to achieve.

[image]

So far I was able to do it like this : [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/j0rhypfq/)

I am not able to get the two column range lined up in same series.
Code snippet how I createad column range:
intWidth: 10

```
        name : 'Type 4',
        type : 'columnrange',
        data : [[],[11.0,11.2],[44.0,44.2],[26.1,26.2],[]],
        color : 'yellow',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve similar effect by disabling `grouping` and setting a proper value of `pointPlacement` and `pointPadding` for all columnrange series.

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/seec2c6q/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.pointPadding
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.pointPlacement
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange.grouping

Comment: I guess its working now. In case I get any issues I will revert you.
Thanks a lot man.